# Apache Flume 1.11.0 throw an error while using this command flume-ng in windows 11 platform

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I've verified the jdk & hadoop in same path and set the enivronment variable.

Successfully installed and set the environment variable for Apache Flume 1.11.0.

After that removed .template in every files located in "C:\apache-flume-1.11.0\conf" directory

Name of removed .template flies

1. flume-conf.properties
2. flume-env
3. flume-env.sh
4. log4j2

Then java jdk path in flume-env.sh file.

After successfully configured the Apache Flume 1.11.0 facing below mentioned issues.

**1.cmd prompt**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d6W4.jpg)

**2.powershell prompt**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIep2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your first image simply says `powershell.exe` isn't a valid executable.

Your second image says there is no `C:\...Flume...\...flume-<ver>-bin\...flume-<ver>-bin\bin\lib` folder

You can literally open that path in File Explorer and see that's true (or not). Seems like you misconfigured some environment variables to triple reference "flume" in the executable path. Double check your flume-env.ps1 / flume-env.bat files and the control panel